# What kind of file path I can use when importing csv into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to import a csv into a dataframe in a way that if the code is copied to another computer the path of the file still points to the correct place inside the project.

I tried this:

```py
csv_filename = '.price/data/table.csv'
df = pd.read_csv('csv_filename', sep=';')
```

It doesn't work.

If I use the full path (`C:\Users\eniko\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\price\data\table.csv`) it works perfect.

So my question would be if there is a method to point to the file inside the Pycharm project when importing the csv, instead of using the full path of the file location?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried csv_filename = './price/data/table.csv'? I am assuming you are using Windows as your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `csv_filename`

```py
csv_filename = '.price/data/table.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename, sep=';')
```